# Mayer-Vietoris sequence for the figure eight

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

On my professor's solutions for my last algebraic topology homework, he gets the following Mayer-Vietoris sequence for the figure eight space (the wedge of two circles):

$0\to H_{2}(X)\to 0\to \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb {Z}\to H_{1}(X)\to \mathbb{Z}\overset{\varphi_{*}}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to0$

I didn't have a problem getting that far, but then he appeals to the "rank theorem" for finitely generated abelian groups, which we proved on a previous homework. For a short exact sequence of finitely generated abelian groups:

$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$

The ranks of the free parts of $A$ and $C$ sum to the rank of the free part of $B$. He appeals to this to claim that it forces $\varphi_{*}$ to be injective, but I don't see how this follows. (He doesn't have any explanation in between and my algebra is not great.) Could someone explain further how the rank theorem implies that $\varphi_{*}$ is injective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you're given an exact sequence
  $$\cdots \to A_3 \stackrel{\psi}{\to} A_2 \to A_1 \to A_0 \to 0,$$
you get a short exact sequence
  $$0\to A_2/\psi(A_3) \to A_1 \to A_0 \to 0.$$
In your case, this gives
  $$0\to \mathbb{Z}/(\text{something})\to \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\to 0.$$
The only way for this to happen is if the "something" is $0$.

Comment: Okay, I see how that implies injectivity, but why is that only possible if the "something" is 0?

Comment: If "something" is not $0$, then $\mathbb{Z}/(\text{something})$ has rank $0$, so the ranks don't add up properly.